# Is this considered a good visualization of clustered data?

Tags: python, clustering, k-means, matplotlib, plotting

I have used sckit-learn to cluster data using K-means (3 clusters). I have an issue with considering the plot as "readable" since clusters are overlapping (even when encircling them)
Any idea how to make the following plot better or is it OK?

[image: matplotlib clusters]

Comment: It's hard to understand what is being plotted here, and normally clusters should be more, well, clustered. Are you using the same x,y data to plot that you use for your clusters? What do the dot colors represent? If it's cluster membership, then it looks like you have data points that belong to more than one cluster.

Comment: `it looks like you have data points that belong to more than one cluster.` i guess yes, but is that a problem? data points I am using are correct. the encircles represent the clusters, some points are overlapped

Comment: the polygones constitute the clusters, there are 3 (red, green and purple)

Comment: So in traditional K-means clustering, each data point is assigned to a single cluster, which would prevent the visualization issues you are seeing here. If you have some more details on how you're doing clustering that would help us help you.

Comment: in the case of redundant values in the data, points will overlap, yielding similar cases

Comment: True, but redundant identical data points get assigned to the same cluster, assuming it's iterating until convergence.

Comment: OK, then I suspect the error is coming from the fact that I apply k-means on the data with full column list, while I am plotting only the selected two dimensions needed for x and y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can run PCA on your higher dimensional data to bring it down to 2 components this will help both the clustering and the visualization.

Comment: what would be the labels/titles for the x and y axis?

Comment: When doing PCA followed by K-means, I've always just used "Component 1", "Component 2"  for the x and y axes, and then indicated the cluster that each data point belonged to with marker color+shape.